# How to write a XSD that will validate tables with different columns count?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have this XSD that works fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="ExportFile">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Part" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element type="xsd:normalizedString" name="PrdCode" />
              <xsd:element type="xsd:normalizedString" name="PrdName" />
              <xsd:element type="xsd:nonNegativeInteger" name="Week1" />
              <xsd:element type="xsd:nonNegativeInteger" name="Week2" />
              <xsd:element type="xsd:nonNegativeInteger" name="Week3" />
              <xsd:element type="xsd:nonNegativeInteger" name="Week4" />
              <xsd:element type="xsd:nonNegativeInteger" name="Week5" />
              <xsd:element type="xsd:nonNegativeInteger" name="Week6" />
              <xsd:element type="xsd:nonNegativeInteger" name="Week7" />
              <xsd:element type="xsd:nonNegativeInteger" name="Week8" />
              <xsd:element type="xsd:nonNegativeInteger" name="Week9" />
              <xsd:element type="xsd:nonNegativeInteger" name="Week10" />
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

How can I change it to validate XMLs containing from 10 to 80 "Week" columns
with sequential names, like: "Week1", "Week2", ... , "WeekN". (10 <= N >= 80)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If they are *sequential* element names, you have to explicitly name them. You will have more flexibility if you use *values* for your sequence of weeks (attribute or child element) instead of changing the element names. Something like `<Week number="1">...</Week>` or `<Week><Number>1</Number>...</Week>`. You can avoid duplicates with uniqueness constraints, and if you use XSD 1.1, even control the ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes when XSD doesn't allow you to do X, it's because X is not a good thing to do. Using structured identifiers (identifiers that encapsulate information about the things they identify) is nearly always a bad idea, and is certainly a bad idea when choosing element names.

Better to replace `<week20>` with `<week nr="20">`.

Having said that, you still need XSD 1.1 to define the constraint that week numbers must be an ascending contiguous sequence. The way to express this constraint in XSD 1.1 would be

```
<xs:assert test="every $i in 1 to count(week) satisfies week[$i]/@nr = $i"/>
```

But then, the `@nr` attribute is actually redundant: you can always work out the week number from its position in the sequence. What's the point of including redundant information in your XML? If you left it out, you wouldn't need to define the constraint.

Comment: Thank you for your very knowledgeable answer.
I still have a problem: in this particular case, the users *require* to be able to see the XML in *tabular* format in Excel. I could write a XSD including:
    <xsd:element type="xsd:nonNegativeInteger" name="Week" minOccurs="12" maxOccurs="84"/>

But Excel cannot handle minOccurs<>1. 
(1) It cannot export using this XSD. 
(2) It does *not* open the corresponding XML as a table with, e.g., 20 “Week” columns.
Am I missing something? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about the restrictions that Excel imposes on the design of the XML. But my instinct would be to design an XML format independent of any Excel-specific constraints, and then when necessary transform it to something viewable in Excel: it's the usual principle of separating logical information structure from presentation.